# Stored procedure auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE @NewID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LastID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2) = RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4) = RIGHT('2' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)),2)


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Statio_Permintaan_Det 
              WHERE RIGHT(permintaand_nmr, 4) = '2020' 
              ORDER BY permintaand_nmr DESC)
    SET @NewID = 'P/0001/AAIJ/' + @Month + '/' + @Year
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @LastID = (SELECT TOP 1 permintaand_nmr 
                   FROM Statio_Permintaan_Det 
                   WHERE RIGHT(permintaand_nmr, 4) = '2020' 
                   ORDER BY permintaand_nmr DESC)
    SET @LastID = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LastID, 3, 4) AS INT) +  1
    SET @NewID = 'P/' + RIGHT('0000' + @LastID, 4) + '/AAIJ/' + @Month + '/' + @Year
END

SELECT @NewID AS NewID
```

When run this program it should be like this `P/0002/AAIJ/04/20` because on the database I already had this id  `P/0001/AAIJ/04/20`, what did I miss?

I have compare this script with another that look like same but I can't figure what the problem is

There is a similiar script but this is work

```
DECLARE @NewID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LastID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2) = RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4) = YEAR(GETDATE())


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Statio_Tentative_Det WHERE RIGHT(tentd_nmr,4)='2020' ORDER BY tentd_nmr DESC)
    SET @NewID = 'T/0001/AAIJ/'+@Month+'/'+@Year
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @LastID = (SELECT TOP 1 tentd_nmr FROM Statio_Tentative_Det WHERE RIGHT(tentd_nmr,4)='2020' ORDER BY tentd_nmr DESC)
    SET @LastID = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LastID,3,4) AS INT) +  1
    SET @NewID = 'T/'+RIGHT('0000' + @LastID,4)+'/AAIJ/'+@Month+'/'+@Year
END


SELECT @NewID as NewID

END
```

Comment: it mostly means that the first select returns a row

Comment: What's the expected output and the actual output?

Comment: yeah exactly, but with a diferent id

Comment: Should be like this `P/0002/AAIJ/04/20` but the script return `P/0001/AAIJ/04/20`

Comment: Year in P/0001/AAIJ/04/20 is 2 digits but you are testing 2020

Comment: i alredy fix that, but still no changes

Comment: Can you edit the question showing your 'fix' of the 2/4 digit year problem?

Comment: from this `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Statio_Permintaan_Det WHERE RIGHT(permintaand_nmr,4)='2020'` to this `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Statio_Permintaan_Det WHERE RIGHT(permintaand_nmr,4)='20'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year in P/0001/AAIJ/04/20 is 2 digits but you are testing 2020

```
create table Statio_Permintaan_Det (permintaand_nmr varchar (100))
go 

insert into Statio_Permintaan_Det values ('P/0001/AAIJ/04/20')

DECLARE @NewID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @LastID VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Month VARCHAR(2) = RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)),2)
DECLARE @Year VARCHAR(4) = RIGHT('2' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)),2)


IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Statio_Permintaan_Det 
              WHERE RIGHT(permintaand_nmr, 2) = '20' 
              ORDER BY permintaand_nmr DESC)
    SET @NewID = 'P/0001/AAIJ/' + @Month + '/' + @Year
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @LastID = (SELECT TOP 1 permintaand_nmr 
                   FROM Statio_Permintaan_Det 
                   WHERE RIGHT(permintaand_nmr, 2) = '20' 
                   ORDER BY permintaand_nmr DESC)
    SET @LastID = CAST(SUBSTRING(@LastID, 3, 4) AS INT) +  1
    SET @NewID = 'P/' + RIGHT('0000' + @LastID, 4) + '/AAIJ/' + @Month + '/' + @Year
END

select @lastid, @newid

------------------------------ ------------------------------
2                              P/0002/AAIJ/04/20

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as the following

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
  Id VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT Test VALUES ('P/0001/AAIJ/04/20'), ('P/0002/AAIJ/04/20');

DECLARE @NewId VARCHAR(45);

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Test WHERE RIGHT(Id, 5) = '04/20')
  SET @NewId = 'P/0001/AAIJ/04/20'
ELSE
  SELECT TOP 1 @NewId = CONCAT('P/', RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', CAST(SUBSTRING(Id, 3, 4) AS INT)+1), 4), '/AAIJ/04/20')
  FROM Test
  ORDER BY Id DESC;

SELECT @NewId;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05f31eb5fd1b7047cc439eb9f2a2c539)